# Cointegration but no Granger causality

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, statistics, time-series, co-integration

Suppose I have two variables - $y_t$ and $x_t$ - which are cointegrated. I believe that (i) $y_t$ responds to deviations from the long-run equilibrium, (ii) the long-run elasticity of $y_t$ with respect to $x_t$ is 1, and (iii) $y_t$ has no contemporaneous effect on $x_t$. I specify the following model:

$$ \Delta y_t = \alpha_0 + \gamma (y_{t-1} - x_{t-1}) + \alpha_1 \Delta x_t + \epsilon_t. $$

Estimating this model gives a negative and significant value for $\gamma$, which seems to confirm (i).

I then test whether past values of $x_t$ Granger-cause $y_t$ as by estimating the following model:

$$ \Delta y_t = \alpha_0 + \gamma (y_{t-1} - x_{t-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \Delta y_t + \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i \Delta x_t + \epsilon_t $$

and testing the hypothesis:

$$ H_0: \gamma=0, \, \beta_i = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad  i. $$

I am unable to reject this hypothesis. Is this a contradiction? Given $x_t$ and $y_t$ are cointegrated, and $\gamma$ in first equation is significant, does that not imply that $x_t$ Granger-causes $y_t$?

Flipping the Granger-causality test, I estimate

$$ \Delta x_t = \alpha_0 + \gamma (x_{t-1} - y_{t-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \Delta x_t + \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i \Delta y_t + \epsilon_t $$

and test the same hypothesis. I find that $y_t$ does Granger-cause $x_t$, but $\gamma$ is very small and insignificant - i.e. $\Delta y_{t-1}$ seems to be the variable with the predictive power. This result is consistent with my prior intuition. It is the result in the other direction that I find confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: I would not read too much into granger causality test. Especially if you don’t have long T it has low power. However, given that the test would be correct I would interpret it in a way that the relationship goes the other way. For example if you know there is long run relationship x=a +by but you estimate it as y=-a +1/bx you should still find cointegration because if the coefficients are significant one way in this simple static LR mode they will be also the other way and the errors will be stationary if there is cointegration too. So maybe you got the direction of causality wrong

Comment: Hi: is your second equation correct ( the one right after, 'I then test" ) because you have $\triangle y_r$ on the LHS and the RHS ? That doesn't feel right. Also, assuming it's not supposed to be there, you add lags of $\triangle y_{t-i}$ compared to the first equation. Maybe it's the lagged changes in $y_t$ that  muddle the predictive power of $\triangle x_t$.

Comment: Hi, Granger non-causality is separate from cointegration. It can be shown that when you reduce the system down to a single equation with error correction as you have here then you are imposing a weak exogeneity assumption. IF this holds, then you can also show that if x does not granger cause y this implies that x is strongly exogenous. By testing for granger causality here you are effectively testing for strong exogeneity given that you have already imposed weak exogeneity. For example, see http://felixpretis.climateeconometrics.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MPhil-Adv-Lec-3.pdf

Comment: Sorry just to be clear, the granger non-causality test would typically be just $\beta=0$ not the joint test you have. The joint test doesn't really tell you anything much of anything other than that jointly the lags don't matter with cointegration which lacks power when lags dont matter at all but error correction term does. For additional sources see: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON5101/v11/undervisningsmateriale/Lect8v11.pdf and https://www.federalreserve.gov/PubS/ifdp/1991/415/ifdp415.pdf